# Probability that $x^2+y^2 \leq 1$ for uniformly distributed random variables.

Tags: probability

$X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$

Find $P(X^2+Y^2\leq1|X\leq Y)$

^conditional probability where | represents given

The final answer is $\frac{\pi}{4}$

So I know that I'm going to have to set up some sort of integral to solve this problem, but I'm confused where to start. Do I need to convert to radians first?

Comment: You are certain the answer is $\frac{\pi}{4}$?

Comment: yes I am, I have an answer key.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $P(X\le Y)=1/2$ and the area of $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}_+^2\ :\ x^2+y^2\le 1 \text{ and }x\le y \}$ is exactly the area of $\{(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)\ :\ r\le 1\text{ and }\theta\in[\pi/4,\pi/2]\}$. Therefore,

\begin{align*}P(X^2+Y^2\le1\,|\,X\le Y)&=\frac{1}{P(X\le Y)}P(X^2+Y^2\le1,\ X\le Y)\\
&=2\int_0^1\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}r\,\mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&=\frac{\pi}{4}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Yes, good answer. I see that range is perfect.(+1)

Answer (score 0):

Geometrically, the question is equivalent to finding the ratio of the area of a circular sector of angle $\pi/8$ and radius $1$, to the area of the isosceles triangle with vertices $(0,0), (0,1), (1,1)$. This is simply $(\pi/8)/(1/2) = \pi/4.$  This is because the locus of points that satisfy $0 \le X \le Y \le 1$ is the aforementioned isosceles triangle, and the added condition that $X^2 + Y^2 \le 1$ obviously corresponds to the intersection of this triangle with the unit disk centered at the origin.

Answer (score -1):

We have $P(X^2 + Y^2 \leq1|X\leq Y)$
Note: $x = rcos\theta, y= r sin\theta$, hence $x^2 +y^2 = r^2$

We have a circle where $x \leq y$, hence a circle $\frac{\pi}{4} \leq \theta \leq \frac{5\pi}{4}$ and radius $0 \leq r \leq 1$

Using this we can construct:
 $$\int_0^1\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{5\pi}{4}} r^3 \mathrm{d\theta dr}$$
$$=\int_0^1 r^3 * \pi \mathrm{dr}$$
$$=[\frac{r^4 * \pi}{4}]_0^1$$
$$=\frac{\pi}{4}$$

Note: $r^3$ is because $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$ then the Jacobian of transformation is $r$.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but it seems to me that you calculated $E[X^2+Y^21_{X\le Y}]=\int_{0}^1\int_{0}^1(x^2+y^2)1_{x\le y}\,\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$, and then did a strange change of variable considering the angle should be between $0$ and $\pi/2$.

Comment: @Ian How is $x\leq y$ at $(1,0)=0$

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the indicator function.

Comment: Maybe you missed that $X,Y$ are nonnegative since they are uniform on $[0,1]$?

Comment: @Ian Sorry, I did indeed miss that.